# running different matlab scripts from different folders by using one script

Tags: matlab

I want to run multiple scripts from different folder by using one script

for example I have the following code:

```
Original_AddRun1 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run\S1.m';
Original_AddRun2 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run2\S2.m';
Original_AddRun3 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run3\S3.m';
Original_AddRun4 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run4\Subfolder\S4.m';

run(Original_AddRun1);
run(Original_AddRun2);
run(Original_AddRun3);
run(Original_AddRun4);
```

there are four scripts that I want to run (S1.m, S2.m, S3.m and S4.m) which are located in the folders (Run, Run2, Run3 and Subfolder inside Run4)

the above Matlab is created inside the "Root" folder that have all the folders

however when i run the code the following error happens

```
Undefined function or variable 'Original_AddRun2'.

Error in AllRun (line 7)
run(Original_AddRun2);
```

the first script runs and I get the figure plot I want but the it stops when it tries to run the second script, each individual script works perfectly and were tested before

**keep in mind** that S2.m needs the variables generated by S1.m to work and the same with S3.m that needs S2.m's generated variables and S4.m needs S3.m's generated variables... this is why those script needs to run in order and `Function` cannot be used because it uses it's own workspace and not the general workspace

I used `save()` to save the general workspace at the end of each script then clear the general workspace to be able to run the next script then used `load()`
in that script to load the variables I need to the general workspace again to use them

I feel there is a much simpler way to do it that the roundabout way `save()` and `load()`

Comment: Maybe you call `clear` in the first script? As a solution, you can use functions instead of scripts.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what happens if you run the scripts manually from the command line. Suppose they are both in your path,
would S1 and then S2 ( after the execution of S1 ) work? Does your S1 have any side effects making the execution of S2 impossible? My best bet would be: do you clear all of your variables at the end of S1 and/or at the beginning of S2, for example? In that case you do not have any variable in the workspace, anymore (that is why Original_AddRun2 is not defined)

Comment: @m7913d @pacta_sunt_servanda I tried using `Clear` but it doesn't work and it's already written in S1.m (`Clear All`) and they cannot be used as function because S2.m uses S1.m's variables and S3.m uses S2.m's variables and so on and Function (As far as I know) doesn't use the general worksapce..... those four script i'm working on are from my friend who asked me to help him with his project for computing muscle energy and each one takes around 1~2 min to finish.... that's why I want to write a code that runs them one by one without me having to stay on the screen and manually do it

Comment: My point was that you should _not_ use `clear` as pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Yes, if you use clear in the first script, it will delete the variables that you store the pathes of S2, S3 and S4 in and thus they will be unknown in the following lines after the call to S1.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to avoid `clear` as much as possible. It should only be used at the top of a main script. The solution is to use a [function workspace](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) (by creating a [function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html)) instead of the global workspace. In this way we avoid cluttering the global workspace.

**main.m:**

```
clear all

Original_AddRun1 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run\S1.m';
Original_AddRun2 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run2\S2.m';
Original_AddRun3 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run3\S3.m';
Original_AddRun4 = 'F:\UPT\Root\Run4\Subfolder\S4.m';

run(Original_AddRun1);
run(Original_AddRun2);
run(Original_AddRun3);
run(Original_AddRun4);
```

**F:\UPT\Root\Run\S1.m:**

```
function S1()
    ... % global variables (ex. Original_AddRun1) are not defined here
    ... % newly defined variables are not added to global scope
end
```

Comment: it doesn't work because each script needs to use the variables in the general workspace that was generated by previously run script and `Function` does't allow that as i said before, i will update the question shortly

Comment: In my opinion, the clean solution is to use function arguments to pass only the needed variables.

Answer (score -1):

I found that when you run a `.m` script from another `.m` script you have to clear the workspace before running another `.m` script in the same process.

Since each script depends on the variables of the previous script in the question that is not directly possible. To avoid this issue and still achieve the objective it is possible to use the `save()` function to save the workspace, then clear it to run the next script, and then load it again with `load()`.
A bit roundabout way of doing it but it works.